# Spark: java.io.InvalidClassException

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

Since moving from a local spark deployment to a standalone cluster, I have been getting the following exception:

> java.io.InvalidClassException:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLRow; local class
>   incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID =
>   -6648071136076699828, local class serialVersionUID = -1718118159864345582

I know exactly when it happens. It happens when I redeploy the shaded jar   from the target directory of build to the Spark master WITHOUT actually recompiling the jar. (This was just a little convenience script for development that clearly doesn't work in a cluster)

However, I don't actually understand the reason for this Exception under these circumstances. How has the serialVersionUID been changed if the class has NOT been recompiled?

Comment: What Scala version is target for local development & what on server? Can you show content of the script?

Comment: exactly the same spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7

Comment: I'm assuming it si related to the streaming of the jars to the slaves...but beyond that have no conceptual understanding of the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had different versions of the `spark-cassandra-connector`
The --packages version was different to the version in my pom.xml. The latter dependency probably being unnecessary outside the test scope of maven